# Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com

Tags: capacitor

having this error message when initializing FCM firebase messanging in logcat of android studio

Answer (score 1):

If you're having above mentioned issue with Android Studio, add the google-services.json file to the android/app folder and compile again. This worked for me for Capacitor / Ionic